# Plunker tags don't work

Tags: search, tags, plunker

Am I the only person on the planet that can't search plunker by tags?  It's so frustrating and it's been this way for me for years.  Furthermore, I can't find anyone else complaining about the same issue. I click the `Tags` tab up top and it takes me to a tags page and it says "Browse Tags" but there's no way to browse anything and no plunks are shown.  So, I've tried going back to the main page with the grid of trending plunks and clicked on a tag like `angular` and it sends me to a separate page and all it says is: "Browsing Angular" but there is no plunks shown, the page is empty.

Comment: Same here, no tags shown

Comment: Same problem i am also facing. I don't understand why they cant put a simple search box.

Comment: Add me to the list. Do they work for anyone else?

Comment: It's a known issue: https://twitter.com/AdamWeeks/status/591251544848240640

Comment: Same. Plunks work fine, but can't search or discover any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, very annoying. They are going to die.